# uninitialized constant while calling worker method in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq gem in rails 3 and I have define a foo_workers.rb in app/workers folder, when I try to call `FooWorker.perform_async(@article)` in a rails controller named `articles` I get this error,

```
uninitialized constant ArticlesController::FooWorker
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Check your pluralization. The file is called `foo_workers.rb`, which means you're probably defining `FooWorkers`, not `FooWorker`. It should be singular. But this is all guessing because you didn't actually post any code.

Answer (score 2):

The autoload mechanism won't pluralize your class names. So the class `FooWorker` is expected to be defined in a `foo_worker.rb` file in some of the autoload paths.

If the file name is different (like `foo_workers.rb`), Rails won't try to load the class from it.